# How to increase SSH lifetime to 1 year?

Tags: windows, ubuntu, ssh, synchronization, rsync

I have an Ubuntu server with rsync installed. And there is Windows 10 for additional file backup with Ubuntu. For this I use VBScript:

```
Set WS = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
WS.CurrentDirectory = "D:\cwrsync\bin"
WS.run "rsync.exe -rvzh -e './ssh' user_name@IP_server:/var/archive/ /cygdrive/D/archive/"
WScript.Sleep 150
Set PipeID = WS.Exec("rsync.exe")
WS.AppActivate (PipeID.ProcessID)
WS.SendKeys ("My_Password~")
```

Task Scheduler regularly executes the script for 30 days. Then the script freezes on entering a password with a message - the password is not correct.

To continue working me need to run the script manually 1 time as an Administrator. And so every 30 days.

Comment: It is not safe to keep password in executable script. The accepted SSH-connection practice is key pair usage. Generate key pair to avoid password input. You should also set SSH-keys expiration time for security reasons.